# Angular2 add/remove class programmatically

Tags: angular, animate.css

in my angular2 login form, if the user inserts wrong credentials, I want to play an animation using [animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/), so I need to add a class and then (?) remove it.

How can I achieve such behavior?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Please provide some code that demonstrates what you try to accomplish. There are many ways depending on what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the template use `ngClass`, on the component itself, use `host: {'[class.someClass]':'someExpression'}` in the `@Component()` annotation, just to name a few.

Answer (score -1):

I found the anwer just reading the official documentation.

This is my working utility class:

```
export class JQueryUtils
{
    public static animateCss (selector:string, animationName:string)
    {
        var jQueryElement = jQuery (selector);
        jQueryElement.addClass ('animated ' + animationName).one ('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend',
        function () {
            jQueryElement.removeClass ('animated ' + animationName);
        });
    }
}
```